# Linking issue with regards to integrating Firebase in existing iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-console

**Update (January 21st)**

Some more details about the problem that I'm trying to solve:

I'm building an iOS app with XCode and my goal is to integrate Firebase to my app so that I can get the crash reports (from Crashlytics) and also the analytics from Firebase. I have followed the instructions on this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup . However, when I attempt to complete the SDK setup with the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), step #4 never finishes and keeps hanging. It looks like the Firebase console isn't recognizing the integration on the client side. Here's a screenshot of the console that I'm referring to:

[image]

Also note that the instruction on the setup instructions page does not ask to use Firestore. Therefore I dont have it in my application delegate. Here's the integration snippets in my application delegate:

```
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

I'm also using CocoaPods to integrate Firebase. The version of Firebase that I'm using is **6.14.0**. Here's the list of libraries that I'm using in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApplication' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 4.6'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13'
    pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.6'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.6'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.6'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.46'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.9'
    pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 3.4'
    pod 'Branch', '~> 0.27'
    pod 'AppsFlyerFramework', '~> 4.10'
    pod 'UIScreenExtension', :git => 'https://github.com/marchv/UIScreenExtension'
    pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'WhirlyGlobe', :git => 'https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe'
    pod 'WhirlyGlobeResources', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'Keychain', '~> 0.3'
    pod 'Purchases', '~> 2.6'
    pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.3'
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

I'm trying to add Firebase to my existing iOS app. I'm following all the steps from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app) but it always hangs at the very last step of the installation process (Step: Run your app to verify installation). I've deleted the app and re-installed. I've made sure that there's only one call to the `FirebaseApp.configure()` statement throughout the whole app. I'm also not using any Firebase database integration in my app. I keep seeing the following in the console when I launch my app:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.

CocoaPods version: 1.6.1
FirebaseCore Version: 6.5
Firebase Version: 6.14

Any idea what's going on and why it wouldn't complete the installation and link my app to the Firebase console? I'm using CocoaPods for integration.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: put breakpoint on `FirebaseApp.configure()`. Does it stop on breakpoint ? what happens after that?

Comment: Deleted the app and reinstalled? You should be running the App within XCode. Do that and step through the code line by line until you run across something unexpected - we need to know what line caused the crash. Then copy and paste that section of code and we'll take a look. You may also want to include your podfile as that can cause the issue as well. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes i put a breakpoint at the `FirebaseApp.configure()` line and it stops on the breakpoint. The app runs normally after that. Just that the backend/console on Firebase doesn't want to complete the integration and it hangs on the las time on the console. @KirilS.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you should include code in your question so we can see what the issue is. What does deleting and re-installing your app have to do with the error in the question? Are you using XCode? *I'm also not using any Firebase database integration in my app* so what is the purpose of Firebase in your app? Did you install Firebase through Cocoapods? Are you including `import Firebase` at the top of your AppDelegate? We really need more complete information to be able to help.

Comment: @Jay Just updated the question with more details. Let me know if that makes sense. Thank you Jay.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, it's weird. When you create a new project in Firebase, it creates a info.plist file (which is Google's), did you put it in your project?

In the 'AppDelegate' file, you must place what the documentation says:

```
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        print(db)

        return true
   }
}
```

Remember, when you create the project in Firebase, you must put your bundle id that appears in your Xcode project.

Comment: Why do you need the `Firestore.firestore()` call here? The documentation doesn't state that it needs this statement. Either way, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @JBYung That call is just for testing in this case. It's not needed but they're trying to narrow down the issue by attempting to print the db object.

Comment: @JBYung, That's right, it's just for testing on "firestore", which shows you the console when you make a print out?

Comment: @DiegoSalazar @Jay Thanks. Really appreciate the prompt response. Looks like whenever I include the pod 'Firebase/Firestore', I get the ```'grpc/support/port_platform.h' file not found``` build error when I build my project. Anything else other than ```Firestore``` that I can use in order to debug the Firebase issue?

Comment: @JBYung See my comment to your question. We really need to see the question updated with pertinent details such as what the podFile looks like and some clarification to the question.

Comment: @Jay Just updated the question. Let me know if that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @JBYung What if you try a new project? I did a test and it works super well, I created a new project in Firebase, I specified the bundle, I included the GoogleService-info.plist to my project, then I initialized CocoaPods in the root (I included 'Firestore/Auth', it's just for testing), finally, I included what the documentation says in the AppDelegate.swift file, and everything worked. Now, it's weird that I don't go on to the next step, to be honest, first time I've seen something like this. Anyway... try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the entire answer but it's part of it.

Looks like you may have overlooked step #2 in the Getting started guide [Add Firebase to your iOS project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Here's a pic of what your podfile should contain for Firebase Firestore

[image]

and the actual text

```
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics' <- this is optional

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth' <- **you have FirebaseAuth
pod 'Firebase/Firestore' <- **this is missing from your podfile**
```

Also note

> You no longer need to add the iOS pod Firebase/Core. This SDK included
>   the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics. Now, to use Analytics (or any
>   of the Firebase products that require or recommend the use of
>   Analytics), you need to explicitly add the Analytics pod:
>   Firebase/Analytics.